# Manage gem dependencies based on Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a gem that works on Ruby 1.9.3, but installing an up-to-date Gemfile works only on Ruby 2.2. Is there a way of separating dependencies based on Ruby versions?

I've seen this approach in the past:

```
pry_debugger = RUBY_VERSION < '2.0.0' ? 'pry-debugger' : 'pry-byebug'
spec.add_development_dependency pry_debugger
```

Or should I just consider supporting one Ruby version (let's say 2.0) and find the supported gems? What's the easiest way of finding what gems work on my local Ruby version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logic like you show will work fine for development dependencies since it will be evaluated at bundle install time.

It will not work for runtime dependencies since the logic will be evaluated at gem-build time and not when the gem runs in another environment.
RubyGems does not provide a way for you to specify different gems based on the runtime environment, so the only way you could support that would be to release two differently named versions of your gem with different gemspecs.

Personally, I don't see the point of putting development dependencies in the .gemspec, so I always just add these to my Gemfile and reserve the gemspec for runtime dependencies only.
This separates the concerns better and makes it clear that gem selection logic can be used in the Gemfile, but not in the gemspec.

Comment: This old [post from Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) mentions why you should use the `gemspec` directive when building gems.

Comment: Yes I definitely use the gemspec directive in my Gemfile to pull in the runtime dependencies.
In fact here is an example: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids/blob/master/Gemfile